# "Grace period" icon missing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911086/net-core-convert-string-to-tagbuilder) has a bounty that ended half an hour ago, but wasn't awarded. So it's in its 24 hour grace period.

Is it on purpose that that's displayed like this:

[image: grace period]

Or is an icon or something missing? I've never seen this before.

Relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="margin-right:4px;float:left;" class="revision-comment">grace period</div>
```

Comment: Probably a new feature. There's also red dots on unread questions in filters

Comment: Ah, you noticed it too - [I asked basically the same thing on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332032/295232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change was [a mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332051/235711) and has been reverted.